# OSError: SavedModel file dors not exist at: ./AstBert_bert

Tags: save, google-colaboratory

I was working on colab I saved my machine learning model and checked that it was well saved before closing the notebook I come back to open the notebook I can't find my model anymore I'm looking in my drive I still can't find it. Where can it be?

Comment: Did you save it to your Drive? or do you just have saved it in Colab sample files. Because Colab sample files will directly be deleted after you closed your notebook.